# I can't see the stroke even though it's in front of other stroke

Tags: grease-pencil

[image]

I can't see the stroke depending on the angle.
I can't see it even though my mouth stroke is in front of skin.
I turned it off and on, but it doesn't work

[image]

Comment: it's a totally different question but the answer is the same: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/299512/168

Comment: Thank you. It works! 3d location.